# Why does the wireless connection on my router keep on disconnecting?

Tags: router, wireless-networking, dd-wrt, connection

The connection seems to be fixed temporarily if I change the wireless channel or power cycle the router.

This is my router model information according to DD-WRT:

- Model: Linksys WRT54G2 / GS2
- Firmware:  DD-WRT v24-sp2 (10/10/09) micro

I use WPA2-Personal security with TKIP+AES.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I recently bought a new wireless router and based on researching hundreds of reviews and web sites, it seems that most consumer-grade wireless routers leave a lot to be desired. Heat is an issue, and with it, reliability issues. I have to reboot my wireless router every 48 hours or so or performance suffers, even for the wired computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible causes:

- Bad router
- Bad wireless card in PC
- Distance between PC and router
- Interference

I'd try getting the two devices close together and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: What do you mean by interference?

Comment: Phones, microwave, walls, just about everything...  Do you have the problem if the devices are close physically?

Comment: I got it already, it was my PS3 with its media server searching enabled. Seems like it causes DoS to the wireless connection. I turned it off and all seemed well. Thanks!